# Open a mail dialog with a large body in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm unfamiliar with angular. However, I'm trying to open a mail dialog with a body like this :

```
$window.location.href = "mailto:?subject=HEY fun?&body=" + body;
```

This works for small bodies due to the URL constraint if I'm correct ? Is there a way around this ?

Answer (score 0):

It is correct. Web browsers pose a de facto limit of 2000 characters (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)).

You could use a `hidden iframe`... See this example hack...:

```
$window.location.href = mailtoHref("mailto:?subject=HEY fun?&body=" + body);

function mailtoHack(href) {
    var iframeHack;
    if (href.indexOf("mailto:") === 0) {
        iframeHack = document.createElement("IFRAME");
        iframeHack.src = href;
        document.body.appendChild(iframeHack);
        document.body.removeChild(iframeHack);
    }
}
```

*Disclaimer: untested code...*